# What are the official phases of penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test

I tried to search for the phases of penetration testing, but I found lots of articles, and each article defines this in a different way, some have 5 phases, some 6, and others 7!

What I am looking for is an official or standard definition of penetration testing phases.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: How are you defining "official" and who's standard would you accept? Why does there need to be a single acceptable standard?

Comment: because when you want to do something in a professional way , you should be following a standard that is agreed by all. so lets say I have a software that I sell to my clients, if I follow a standard of pentesting, I will confidently tell my clients, my software undergoes pentesting according to standard x.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I asked why you think there needs to be a ***single acceptable*** standard. You can accomplish what you've stated by simply saying "I followed Standard X". You don;t need Standard X to be the only standard ... You also don't specify what you are testing. An app? web app? network? Each has their own steps and standards....

Comment: ah okay I see your point, maybe I want a standard that is well known and authentic. A standard that gives confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universally agreed definition of what "penetration testing" is, let alone how many phases it has.

The term is used to mean anything from running a vulnerability scanner and calling it a day, all the way up to multi-month objective-based engagements including technical, social engineering and physical attacks against an organisation.

There are various "standards" like [OSSTMM](https://www.isecom.org/OSSTMM.3.pdf) (PDF) and [PTES](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page), and other standards like PCI DSS define what *they* mean by "penetration test" - but none of these are widely accepted as authoritative.

Comment: ahh okay thanks a lot! I didn't know about PTES before, if we want to rank them, which one comes first? or it hard to determine this?

Comment: OSSTMM is a much more formal and academic standard. That has advantages, but also makes it much harder to implement in the real world. But which is is "better" depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Related xkcd https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Okay, so what I am trying to implement is, that I want a standard to follow to document the pentest process and to be able to implement it on a real case scenario. 
So for example, in phase 1 I want to document everything needed in this phase as a checklist, and when we want to conduct the pentest, we go over the checklist , this way we are sure we are covering all the phases and in alignment with a authoritative standard.